# Table with fixed width centering won't compile

Tags: tables

All, I don't think I've ever been this stuck. The following compiles. But if I uncomment the commented line, it does not compile. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{>{\centering}p{2cm} |}}\toprule
%$x$ & $p$ & $xp$ & $x^2p$ \\\midrule
2 & 0.1 & &\\
3 & 0.2 & &\\
4 & 0.2 & &\\
5 & & &\\\midrule
$\sum x=$ & $\sum p=$ & $\sum xp=$ & $\sum x^2p=$ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` since `\centering` redefines `\\` (I removed the vertical lines since their use won't produce noce results, more if `booktabs`' features are in use):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} }}\toprule
$x$ & $p$ & $xp$ & $x^2p$ \\\midrule
2 & 0.1 & &\\
3 & 0.2 & &\\
4 & 0.2 & &\\
5 & & &\\\midrule
$\sum x=$ & $\sum p=$ & $\sum xp=$ & $\sum x^2p=$ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{>{\centering}p{2cm} }}\toprule
$x$ & $p$ & $xp$ & $x^2p$ \tabularnewline\midrule
2 & 0.1 & &\tabularnewline
3 & 0.2 & &\tabularnewline
4 & 0.2 & &\tabularnewline
5 & & &\tabularnewline\midrule
$\sum x=$ & $\sum p=$ & $\sum xp=$ & $\sum x^2p=$ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I also ask how I can left-justify the entries in the bottom row?

Comment: @user16203 sure. You can use `\multicolumn{1}{l}{$\sum...$}` for each cell.